# WSO2 HTTPServletRequest Object null parameters in POST request

Tags: rest, post, wso2, httprequest, wso2-esb

Using WSO2 ESB 4.8.0 i m trying to write a mediator and to expose it via HTTP REST mode.
In the axis2.xml i have modified this code lines.

```
<transportReceiver class="org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.http.HttpTransportListener" name="http">
    <parameter locked="false" name="port">8280</parameter>
    <parameter locked="false" name="non-blocking">true</parameter>
    <!--parameter name="bind-address" locked="false">hostname or IP address</parameter-->
    <!--parameter name="WSDLEPRPrefix" locked="false">https://apachehost:port/somepath</parameter-->
    <parameter locked="false" name="httpGetProcessor">org.wso2.carbon.transport.nhttp.api.PassThroughNHttpGetProcessor</parameter>
    <!--<parameter name="priorityConfigFile" locked="false">location of priority configuration file</parameter>-->
</transportReceiver>
```

So now the Proxy service containing the mediator is published on the 9763 port.
Inside the mediator i have this code lines:

```
org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext axis2MsgContext;
axis2MsgContext =  ((Axis2MessageContext) synapseMsgContext).getAxis2MessageContext();
HttpServletRequest obj = (HttpServletRequest)axis2MsgContext.getProperty(HTTPConstants.MC_HTTP_SERVLETREQUEST);

if (obj != null) {
    System.out.println("Method :"+ obj.getMethod());
    System.out.println("Content-type :" +obj.getContentType());
    System.out.println("Content-length :"+obj.getContentLength());
    System.out.println("Remote addtress"+obj.getSession().getLastAccessedTime());  
    obj.getParameter("param");
}
```

I try to send POST REST request using some REST client (poster on firefox, or the advanced rest client on chrome).
I realize that

```
obj.getParameter("param")
```

is not null only if i append the parameters to the url request as a query string.
If in a post request i put the parameters in the body payload, the previous function returns just NULL value.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting values for GET request but not for other HTTP Verbs?

What the following returns incase of POST request?

```
 obj.getMethod()
```

Comment: i'm trying to get the parameter sent in a POST request inside the body of a mmessage. I'm using REST clients like Mozilla Poster or Google Chrome Plugin: Advanced Rest Client. I append the parameter in the request body and then i try to get them back using obj.getParameter("param")... I get Null values in this case. On the other side i get not a NULL value only if i append the parameters in the request URL as a query (but that's wrong for POST request and right just for GET request)